# Laravel conditional api resource element

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get returned `region` via my Laravel API resource. `region` is a relation to other table, so I'm accessing it by:

```
return [
   'region' => ['name' => $this->region->name, 'type' => $this->region->type],
];
```

and this works until region value is not null. If region value is null - it gives me an error - cannot take name of undefined -  so I tried to stop it from happening by simply:

```
   'region' => $this->when($this->region, function(){    
      return ['name' => $this->region->name, 'type' => $this->region->type];
    }),
```

and it works, but the problem is - when `region` value in the table is `NULL` - it gives no 'region' empty array as result - which I need in frontend, so I tried to make it this way:

```
            'region' => $this->when($this->region, function(){
                return ['name' => $this->region->name, 'type' => $this->region->type];
            }),
            'region' => $this->when(!$this->region, function(){
                return ['name' => '', 'type' => ''];
            }),
```

but this is not working - no empty region array inside results :/

Am I doing something wrong here, or is it a bug?

Comment: where are you returning `region`?

Answer (score 0):

it's easier than you think, you could use the Optional helper object for null objects

```php
return [
   'region' => [
       'name' => optional($this->region)->name, 
       'type' => optional($this->region)->type
    ],
];
```

[Laravel Method Optional Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-optional)